# Linux Terminal CAT CUT COMMAND

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to Save all groups, both system and common, from the group file and alphabetically in a .txt file. but in the terminal the result is:

the option requires an argument - "d"

I have the following code so far:

cat my_group | cut-d "" | sort> grupos.txt

thanks

Comment: space between cut and -d. You will also need to specify a field as well. Maybe cut -d ":" -f 1?

Answer (score 1):

The fields are delimited by : in a typical /etc/group file with the group names as the first field and so the cut command will need to represent this:

```
cut -d ":" -f 1 < my_group | sort > grupos.txt
```

Also don't needlessly use cat. You can simply redirect the file into the cut command and pipe into sort